# How to check the type of a variable against another variable in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an array of classes, and I want to check if a certain variable matches a certain element in that array. This is what I would do in Objective-C:

```
NSArray *arrayOfClasses = @[UIButton.class, UILabel.class];
Class aClass = arrayOfClasses[0];
UIButton *button = [UIButton new];

if ([button isKindOfClass:aClass]) {
    NSLog("button is aClass")
}
```

But I can't figure out a way to do it in Swift:

```
let arrayOfClasses = [UIButton.self, UILabel.self]
let aClass = arrayOfClasses[0] as! NSObject.Type
let button = UIButton()

if button is aClass {
    NSLog("button is aClass")
}
```

The code above throws an error saying `'aClass' is not a type`. I've also tried `as! AnyClass`, `as! AnyClass.Type`, `as! AnyObject.Type`, etc.

---

**Updated:**
Thanks to @matt, I now know how to get it to work in pure Swift. But if `arrayOfClasses` is created in Objective-C, it crashes with an error `Could not cast value of type 'DummyA' (0x1049f48a0) to 'Swift.AnyObject.Type'`. That make sense, because the Objective-C class is now an AnyObject in swift, and it can't convert that AnyObject to an AnyClass.

Here's the sample code:

```
@interface DummyA : NSObject
+ (NSArray *)dummies;
@end

@interface DummyB : NSObject
@end

@implementation DummyA
+ (NSArray *)dummies
{
    return @[[DummyA class], [DummyA class], [DummyB class], [DummyB class]];
}
@end

@implementation DummyB
@end


let arrayOfClasses = DummyA.dummies()
let aClass: AnyClass = arrayOfClasses[0] as! AnyClass // crash!
```

I finally found a way to make it to work, but that looks too weird to be the right way!

```
let aClass = NSClassFromString( NSStringFromClass( object_getClass(arrayOfClasses[0]) ))
// aClass is (AnyClass!) $R0 = DummyA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tricky, isn't it? I think this will do it:

```
let arrayOfClasses : [AnyClass] = [UIButton.self, UILabel.self]
let AClass : AnyClass = arrayOfClasses[0]
let button = UIButton()
let ok = button.dynamicType === AClass // true
```

Line 1: If you don't declare the type of `arrayOfClasses` explicitly, you get an implicit array of AnyObject, and that's going to give you trouble later because an AnyObject can't be a class.

Line 2: AClass will implicitly be AnyClass, which is right, but we need explicit typing to quiet a warning from the compiler.

Line 3: No problem there.

Line 4: Well, basically you just have to know that this is a way to ask whether one thing's type is another given type. The class of `button`, as a class object, is its `dynamicType`, so now you can ask, is this the very same class object as whatever class object AClass is.

---

EDIT: You've edited the question so that the array of classes comes from Objective-C, but I don't see how that really changes anything:

```
let arrayOfClasses = DummyA.dummies()
let AClass : AnyObject = arrayOfClasses[0]
let button = UIButton()
let ok = button.dynamicType === AClass.self
```

Comment: What I still don't understand is that in my implementation, why it says `'aClass' is not a type` while it's clearly a `Type` when I check it in the debugger? Is it a bug or I misunderstand something?

Comment: I explained that in my discussion of Line 1, when I said "an AnyObject can't be a class". As long as this thing is typed as an AnyObject, it cannot stand in where a type is expected (even if it _is_ a type underneath). And in any case, your implementation as shown would never even get off the ground - it will crash on the second line.

Comment: hey @matt, thanks for your previous answer, but I'm chocked again when dealing with array of classes from Objective-C. Would you mind take a look at my updated question?

Comment: hm sorry i'm not quite sure what you meant. I just find it weird to have to convert it back and forth with `NSClassFromString( NSStringFromClass(...))`. It feels like I should able to simply use `object_getClass(arrayOfClasses[0])`.

Comment: See my updated answer and please stop moving the goalposts. :)

Comment: Thank you! I re-read the Metatype section in the docs and it makes more sense now.