# Test if a list contains element of specific type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm currently trying to write some code that checks to see a list contains an element of a given type T, and am running into trouble. Essentially, this list contains a multitude of elements of different types - however, each of those types are subclassed from one parent type. I've tried

```
class Entity { }
class Goal : Entity { }
class Player : Entity { }

var entities = [Entity]()
entities.append(Player())

func listContainsClass<T: Entity>(var list: [Entity]) -> Bool {
    for entity in entities {
        if entity is T {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

let contains = listContainsClass<Goal>(entities)
```

In this case, I get a compiler error stating *"cannot explicitly specialize a generic function"*. If I try to run the function without specifying a generic argument (by only typing `listContainsClass(entities)`) the compiler exits with a seg-fault 11 code and xCode crashes, which is a separate issue.

I've also tried passing the class type as a parameter instead:

```
func listContainsClass(var list: [Entity], var type: Entity.Type) -> Bool {
    for entity in entities {
        if entity === type {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

let contains = listContainsClass(entities, Player.self)
```

But am unsure how to make it work, as it always returns false. Perhaps this is just an old way of thinking, since I am coming from an obj-c background.

Any help on the proper way to do this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using a generic at all? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Also, this makes no sense: `<T: Entity>` That says that Entity is a protocol. But it isn't, it's a class, so you can't say that.

Comment: The goal of the function is to look through a list of entities, and return true if a specific sub-class (in this case, a "Goal" entity) exists in that list, or false if the list does not contain an element of that type

Comment: Gotcha. See my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close! Use your second (nongeneric) implementation, and:

```
if entity.dynamicType === type {
```

Comment: Ahh, that did it! Thank you very much. Can't mark your answer as correct for another 9 minutes yet, but I will :)

Comment: BTW this is remarkably similar to this, which came up just yesterday I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632163/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-variable-against-another-variable-in-swift

Comment: Haha looks like your a pro at these kinds of questions. I had come across some stuff with triple ='s, but didn't run into your previous answer. Thanks for the additional reference though!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to check is to just use the built-in contains function:

```
contains(entities, { $0 is Player } )
```

One difference between this and the function you're building is that this will accept further subclasses, where as your function (using ===) won't.